# Creating an image file with count PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

For all of the records my code loops through them displaying them each in turn. Now I want to add an image for each of them.

To do this I am going to use the file path not BLOB because I can't for this project.

So far I have the code posted below but I am struggling to implement the count function as I want to the number of the file to increment each time. My files are stored as images/Starter1.jpg, images/Starter2.jpg etc.

```
<div id = "starters">
    <p class = "big"> Starters </p>
    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_starters)){
        $count = 0; 
        echo "<div id = item> ".
        "<p>".
        "<b>Name: </b> ". $row["name"].
        "<img src = images/Starter".$count.".jpg width = 100px, height = 100px>".
        "<br><br><b>Price: </b>&pound;". $row["price"].
        "<br><br><a href=menuInfo.php?ID=".$row["productID"]."><button type = button> See more details </button></a>".
        "<br><br><button type = button> Add to favourites </button>".
        "<br><br><button type = button> Add to basket </button>".   
        "</p>". 
        "</div>";
        $count = $count + 1;
    }
    ?>
</div> <!-- For starters -->
```

Comment: For one thing `<img src = images/Starter` is missing a quote before `images` folder, which will error out as a parse error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At each iteration you're putting back $count variable to 0. "Initialize" the variable outside of the loop the increment would work.

You could also increment in a more nice way than `$count = $count + 1;` by just doing `++$count;`

And don't forget to put quote in the html properties.

```
<div id = "starters">
    <p class = "big"> Starters </p>
    <?php
    $count = 0; 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_starters)){
        ?>
        <div id ="item">
            <p>
                <b>Name: </b><?php echo $row["name"]; ?>
                <img src="images/Starter<?php echo $count; ?>.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
                <br><br><b>Price: </b>&pound;<?php echo $row["price"]; ?>
                <br><br><a href="menuInfo.php?ID=<?php echo $row["productID"]; ?>"><button type="button"> See more details </button></a>
                <br><br><button type="button"> Add to favourites </button>
                <br><br><button type="button"> Add to basket </button>
            </p>
        </div>
    <?php
        ++$count;
    }
    ?>
</div> <!-- For starters -->
```

Comment: `++$count` is a nicer way to write `$count = $count + 1;`.

Comment: @D4V1D I didn't want it to fix it at first but now that you said it I edited my post thanks ;-)

Comment: *And don't forget to put quote in the html properties as src for img* - I take it you saw my comment ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I got to say yes `:-P`

Comment: Thank you! I just couldn't see what was wrong!
@D4V1D Also thanks too. I was thinking about the concise way you do it in JavaScript and when that way didn't work I just wrote it out the long way